# Setup customer creation across multiple websites

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We are running a Magento instance that is running three websites. Each website representing a country.  We want to know is there an easy way , in admin console in 2.1.x ,to allow a customer to register across the three websites ? When I go to customers in the admin console I see that I can assign a customer to one of the 3 websites using a drop down menu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have the same login for a customer work at multiple websites within Magento 2.

You'll want to enable the "global" option for account sharing, so that the same login can be used at different websites.

Stores --> Configuration --> Customers --> Customer Configuration:
[image: Global Option for account sharing]

If you set it up this way, the user can now login at any of the three websites.

If you have three different domains, and want the user to be able to add products on one website, go to the second website and add additional products and then checkout with a cart that combines them all... then you'll need to add in a session variable into the URL string that will allow Magento to know that this the same user across multiple domains (or subdomains, if you're setting a cookie domain).  Otherwise, if a user is on website1.com and goes to website2.com, their session will not be transferred over.

You'll find the configuration here: Stores --> Configuration --> Web --> Session Validation Settings

You'll want to enable use SID on storefront:
[image: Magento 2 Session Validation Settings]

I hope this helps!

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thanks for that Jeff.

Comment: Hello Jeff. What is a good email o reach you on?

Comment: Best way to reach me is through our website (I don't want to post my email due to spam reasons): http://www.customerparadigm.com/Magento/

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :) made my day!!!

Comment: I have already enable this option and set to Global still when I am switching website, its asking me again to login.